# Classe DAL é necessária para conexão com banco de dados?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, conexão

É necessário criar um arquivo para conexão de banco? Segundo um professor de um colega meu é necessário ter essa classe DAL para fazer a conexão com o banco. Mas o livro pelo qual estou me baseando não fala nada. O arquivo `mdf` não é responsável por isso?

Comment: Não sei se é fácil responder sem ter mais dados. Mas em princípio DAL não é necessária para conectar ao bando de dados. Mas o tal professor pode estar falando de outra coisa que seu amigo não entendeu direito e passou outra coisa para você que entendeu uma terceira. Pode ser um problema de telefone sem fio. O arquivo `mdf` é algo para o banco de dados armazenar os dados que ele precisa, em princípio não importa para sua aplicação. A não ser que você esteja falando de alguma outra coisa que não esteja clara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## É necessário criar um arquivo para conexão de banco?

Não. O contexto + as `connection strings` definidas no seu arquivo `Web.config` já fazem isso.

## O arquivo `mdf` não é responsável por isso?

**MDF** (*Master Data File*) é um banco de dados completo, e não uma DAL. Ele é usado quando não existe um servidor de banco de dados instalado na sua máquina, mas é bastante limitado e não recomendado para desenvolvimento extensivo de aplicações.

Comment: Você poderia dar um exemplo de quando utilizar a DAL?

Comment: Você usa DAL quando precisa definir em detalhes a camada de acesso a dados. Se o seu sistema utiliza algum Framework de acesso a dados como o Entity Framework ou o nHibernate, isto não é necessário porque estes Frameworks já possuem uma lógica de acesso a dados pronta.

Comment: Obrigado. Agora ficou mais claro. No caso, se eu desenvolver um projeto sem algum framework de acesso, eu devo utilizar a DAL, correto? No meu caso eu tô desenvolvendo o projeto final da faculdade, acredito que o mdf consiga suprir as minhas necessidades, certo?

Comment: @RyanSantos Acredito que sim, embora eu não goste de trabalhar muito com ele. É muito suscetível a falhas.